# Is there any way to quickly check if a partial order is transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, set-theory, order-theory

Is there any fail safe and quick way to check if a partial order $\preceq$ on a set $A$ is transitive without checking through trial and error?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting if topological sorting succeeds, the ordering is transitive.  Anything less is insufficient, because it only takes one naughty edge to break it.

Comment: The answer depends entirely on how the partial order is defined or given to you.

Comment: all partial orders are transitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shall solve this problem by using a bit of graph theory.

First draw the **directed,acyclic** graph of the partially ordered set $(A,\preceq)$. Then compute the **adjacency matrix**, $M$, of the graph.

Note that in general for all graphs *G* and for all positive integers *k*, the $(i,j)$th entry of $M^{k}$ gives the number of walks of length $k$ between $v_{i}$ and $v_{j}$.

Now we find $M^{2}$, whose $(i,j)$th entry will give the total number of walks of length $2$ between $v_{i}$ and $v_{j}$. So for every non-zero entry of $M^{2}$, we just need to check if it's corresponding entry in $M$ is non-zero,and if it's the case, then the partial order $\preceq$ is transitive indeed!